# A/C Condensor fan turns on when Heater is switched on

Tags: ac, heater

I have a Mitsubishi Lancer. I recently got the fan control module changed. However, I have noticed that when I turn the heater on, the A/C condenser fan also turns on. Is this right? I do feel that it is counter intuitive. If wrong what could be the problem?

Furthermore, previously when the car is heated up the radiator fan worked for a while after the engine was switched off. Now this does not happen even if the engine was overheating (due to bad A/C fan which I replaced after I got the control module fixed.)

Could someone would be able to help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! This is new behavior? Or you just hadn't noticed it before? The reason I state this is, it is common for the A/C compressor to kick on when the defrost is turned on (in most vehicles). When the A/C is on, the fan for the condenser is turned on automatically. This could be the reason for that portion of it. If the fans are not turning on, even when overheating, this would be a separate control issue which might mean a temp sensor is bad. The A/C fans and coolant fans are two separate processes, though both are controlled by the ECU (ultimately).

Comment: Thanks. The behavior (only the fans wont run for a while when engine is hot and turned off.) I noticed after I got the control module changed. However, I have not turned the defroster on (I suspect that is the button that removed the fog from the rear window?) still the A/C condenser fan turns on when the cabin heater is on. (However, the A/C button is on). Thanks & Best Regards